# Comparison between two elements

Tags: grammaticality

When comparing two elements, should we use "more" or "most"? Example: "There are two locations, you can choose the more/the most convenient one."

Answer (score 0):

Most is defined as "to *the* greatest extent".
More is defined as "to *a* greater extent".
If there are two elements to choose from, I would use "more" because one is either more or less than the other.
If there are more than two, I would use "most" because one will be greater than *all* the others.  One of them may be more than another, but may also be less than another, so it would not be the preferred one.  Only one option would be the *most* preferable.